# Cannot select an item from autocomplete when there is button or text input behind the item

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I cannot click the 1st and 2nd item because there is text input behind it and 3rd and 4th item because of the button behind it. 5th item is clickable. I tried using zindex but it does not work. I am using react-native-autocomplete-input library.

It works fine in iOS but not in Android

This is my code

```
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  TouchableOpacity as Touchable,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

<View style={[styles.inputContainer, globalStyles.zIndex1]}>
                <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>{getSupplierLabel()}</Text>
                <Autocomplete
                  editable={true}
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  data={filteredParties}
                  onChangeText={(text: string) => {
                   //some code
                  }}
                  value={party}
                  flatListProps={{
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'always',
                    keyExtractor: (party: any) => party.id,
                    renderItem: ({item: {name}}: any) => (
                      <Touchable
                        style={[globalStyles.margin10, globalStyles.zIndex1]}
                        onPress={() => {
                          setFilteredParties([]);
                          setParty(name);
                        }}>
                        <Text textColor={color.gray}>{name}</Text>
                      </Touchable>
                    ),
                  }}
                  inputContainerStyle={globalStyles.borderWidth0}
                  listContainerStyle={styles.autocompleteListContainerStyle}
                  containerStyle={styles.textInput}
                />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 2,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: color.gray,
    borderRadius: 2,
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  autocompleteListContainerStyle: {
    left: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 41,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your AutoComplete component with a view and give it a suitable zIndex :

```
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  TouchableOpacity as Touchable,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

<View style={[styles.inputContainer, globalStyles.zIndex1]}>
                <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>{getSupplierLabel()}</Text>
                <View style={  zIndex: 2 }>
                <Autocomplete
                  editable={true}
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  data={filteredParties}
                  onChangeText={(text: string) => {
                   //some code
                  }}
                  value={party}
                  flatListProps={{
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'always',
                    keyExtractor: (party: any) => party.id,
                    renderItem: ({item: {name}}: any) => (
                      <Touchable
                        style={[globalStyles.margin10, globalStyles.zIndex1]}
                        onPress={() => {
                          setFilteredParties([]);
                          setParty(name);
                        }}>
                        <Text textColor={color.gray}>{name}</Text>
                      </Touchable>
                    ),
                  }}
                  inputContainerStyle={globalStyles.borderWidth0}
                  listContainerStyle={styles.autocompleteListContainerStyle}
                  containerStyle={styles.textInput}
                />
                </View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 2,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: color.gray,
    borderRadius: 2,
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  autocompleteListContainerStyle: {
    left: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 41,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
});
```